# Value depending of the position of the newest date

Tags: excel

I tried to create cell showing the status of product depending of his newest movement.

I already tried this, but I did not distinguish the Removal and the Return status.

```
=IF(AND([@[Last arrival]]>[@[Last installation]];[@[Last arrival]]>[@[Last removal]];[@[Last arrival]]>[@[Last return]]);"Warehoused";IF(AND([@[Last installation]]>[@[Last arrival]];[@[Last installation]]>[@[Last removal]];[@[Last arrival]]>[@[Last return]]);"Installed";"Had a defect/Sent for repair"))
```

It works, but the problem is if I want to add other type of movement, the code will grow exponentially.

Here an example of my table (it was transposed for reading convenience):

- Last arrival: 19/02/12
- Last installation: 28/02/12
- Last removal: none
- Last return: none
- Status: Installed

Is there a way, with simple functions or VBA code, to compare all the dates once and return a specific value?
Thank you for reading, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dates are in cells B2, B3, B4, and B5 then you would use the worksheet function MAX. Try `=MAX(B2:B5)` in that case.

It will probably require that you don't have the word 'None' in the cells. If that is necessary, then create another column to have only dates or blanks.

Comment: I am sorry if my explanation was too vague, but my problem is not to display the newest date, but to determine which date is the newest.

Comment: Try =MATCH(MAX(B2:B5),B2:B5,0). That will give you the position in the list of the latest date. You should be able to work with that to get what you need.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this function. Thank you!